# Changing the page following each chapter

Tags: graphics, titlesec

I'm currently using the `titlesec` package and `TikZ` to modify chapter and section headings (see attached image). Notice the dark gray box where the chapter number is displayed. My question is: is there any way I could create a corresponding box on the page immediately after a chapter heading (the backside of the paper). Is it at all possible to modify a different page than the page of the header itself?

I guess I could define a custom pagestyle and manually set it for each chapter as a quick-fix, but it would be nice to have something automatic.

Any suggestions?

Here's a minimal example of how I generate the headings. 
The desired result would be a dark gray box in the top-left corner of pages 2 and 4, such that it lines up with the backside of the gray box in pages 1 and 3.
I didn't provide any code earlier because I don't know where to start looking.
All examples I've found so far deal with modifying the same page as the chapter heading.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[vmargin=2.5cm, rmargin=2.5cm, lmargin=2.5cm]{geometry} % Adjust page margins
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit, pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{bold-extra}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{darkgray}{gray}{0.65}

\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}

\titleformat{name=\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}\normalfont\Large\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[draw=none, yshift=-7cm] at (current page.north west) {
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[draw=none, fill=lightgray] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[draw=none, anchor=west,yshift=1.5cm,xshift=1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin, text width=\textwidth, inner sep=0, outer sep=0]{\huge{#1}};
        \node[draw=none, anchor=south east,rectangle, xshift=\paperwidth, inner sep=6pt, fill=darkgray, minimum height=3cm, minimum width=2.5cm]{\Huge \chapterlabel};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    };
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \vspace{1cm}
  }

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\section{Section}

\chapter{Another chapter}
\section{Section}

\end{document}
```

-Thomas-

[image: current style]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The answer to both of your questions is "in principle, yes." Please show us the code you've used so far.

Comment: Added code for the heading styles, but I don't even know where to start on the actual problem I described. That's why I didn't include any code.

Comment: The afterpage package should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much, the `afterpage` package worked nicely. As a side question: are you aware of similar packages that would allow something to happen at arbitrary offsets N-k or N+k?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comment by John Kormylo, the [`afterpage`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/afterpage?lang=en) package can be used for this. 
This is an updated example showing the effect.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[vmargin=2.5cm, rmargin=2.5cm, lmargin=2.5cm]{geometry} % Adjust page margins
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit, pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{bold-extra}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{darkgray}{gray}{0.65}

\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}

\titleformat{name=\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}\normalfont\Large\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[draw=none, yshift=-7cm] at (current page.north west) {
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[draw=none, fill=lightgray] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[draw=none, anchor=west,yshift=1.5cm,xshift=1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin, text width=\textwidth,     inner sep=0, outer sep=0]{\huge{#1}};
        \node[draw=none, anchor=south east,rectangle, xshift=\paperwidth, inner sep=6pt, fill=darkgray,     minimum height=3cm, minimum width=2.5cm]{\Huge \chapterlabel};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    };
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \vspace{1cm}
    \afterpage{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[draw=none, yshift=-7cm] at (current page.north west) {
          \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \node[draw=none, anchor=south west,rectangle, fill=darkgray, minimum height=3cm, minimum width=1cm]{};
          \end{tikzpicture}
          };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
  }

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\section{Section}
\chapter{Another chapter}
\section{Section}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image]